# Can't connect to Flask-Socketio via wss but works via ws

Tags: flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have built a Flask-Socketio server application which works as expected when I connect to it using a javascript client via ws, but fails to connect via wss, both on localhost and when running on my Digital Ocean server. With wss, I get this error in the console (client running on Heroku):

```
index.js:14 WebSocket connection to 'wss://[IP_ADDRESS]/socket.io/? 
EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error in connection establishment: 
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

When the client is running on localhost, it causes this error:

```
polling-xhr.js:265 GET https://localhost:5000/socket.io/? 
EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MW6p0Aj net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

The flask server is running with

`socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=443) # production`
or

`socketio.run(app, host="localhost", port=5000) # localhost`

At first I thought it could have been an issue with the Nginx configuration or server ports not being open, however the same issue occurs with the server running on Localhost, so now I'm suspecting an issue with my Flask-Socketio application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have SSL certificates configured. I followed the instructions in [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04) to create a self-signed SSL certificate and configure Nginx to use it. Now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of issues with Flask-Socketio. With Apache server it almost doesn't works.But you are using Nginx. Refer following link on github.

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/298#issuecomment-408682588